# How to connect postgreSQL to c++

Tags: postgresql, compiler-errors, c++20

I have been following this video to install the linkage between postgreSQL and C++ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDiC1Wja6Og), and after following all the steps, i get this error: "The code execution cannot proceed because LIBPQ.dll was not found." even though i went into the postgreSQL directory and found the file. I have no clue how to fix it, i've tried reinstalling postgres and i've restarted my pc each time it was needed. Any clues or solutions would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put libpq.dll into directory of your project build also you need to add
libeay32.dll,
libiconv-2.dll and
libintl-8.dll.
You can take all these libraries from Postgres installation

```
|---app.exe
|---libpq.dll
|---libeay32.dll
|---libiconv-2.dll
|---libintl-8.dll
```

or add path to libpq.dll into the path environment of your os